# rails 4 update record without using default update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update a model record without using the default update method. I want to use my custom method to update it.
I want to use custom method like

```
def update_record do
end
```

The problem is whenever I retrieve a record, it automatically calls update method, instead of my custom method as shown below:

```
<%= form_for([@promotion], url: {action: :update_record}) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

I have added rout.

```
  resources :promotions do
    collection {
      post :update_record
    }
  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put your routes.rb

Comment: I have updated rout code.

Comment: Make a 'rake routes' too if you can please

Comment: Actuality here I used the general term not the my application specific.

Comment: I always use 'collection do' instead of {} but I can't see anything else wrong

Comment: Ok, but it should not effect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67849/discussion-between-pabliiitoo-and-naushad-khan).

Comment: Have you tried with put or patch instead of post ?

Comment: No, I didn't try that.

Comment: @NickCatib, yes it works with patch. what is the reason ?

Comment: The reason is that you use resource: Every HTTP Method has its own purpose. GET for show, POST for create etc.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the method from POST to patch:

```
resources :promotions do
    collection {
      patch :update_record
    }
  end
```